# Getting an error "string index out of range" in python

Tags: python, string, indexing, range, out

I was creating a code to encode an input word.Letters in the input text is converted to a number and stored in a list.Here is the code I used,

```
z=input("input the word:")
x= z.strip()
y= -1
g=[ ]

while y<=len(x):
   y=y+1
   if x[y]==" ":
       g.insert(y,1000)
   if x[y]=="a":
     g.insert(y,1001)
   if x[y]=="b":
       g.insert(y,1002)
```

and so on.....

But I was getting an error ,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\enc.py", line 13, in <module> 
if x[y]==" ": 
IndexError: string index out of range 

>>>
```

It would be grateful if anyone showed me what's wrong in the code.

Comment: The loop condition is `y <= len(x)`, so it will attempt to index at `len(x)` and will raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: You should increment `y` at the end of the loop body, not the beginning.

Comment: Why don't you just use `for char in x:`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list: index out of range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058778/python-list-index-out-of-range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your loop.  You will run the loop even when y == len(x), and you bump the `y` first thing.  So if the string is 3, you'll do the loop with y==4, when even `x[3]` is out of range.  Just use a for loop.  That's what they're for.

```
z=input("input the word:")
x= z.strip()
g=[ ]
for y in range(len(x)):
   if x[y]==" ":
       g.insert(y,1000)
   elif x[y]=="a":
       g.insert(y,1001)
   elif x[y]=="b":
       g.insert(y,1002)
```

I would probably use `for y,c in enumerate(x):`, but we'll leave that as an exercise for later.

So, even better:

```
g=[]
for c in x:
    if c==' ':
        g.append(1000)
    elif c=='a':
        g.append(1001)
    elif c=='b':
        g.append(1002)
```

An even better approach would be data-driven:

```
mapping = {
    ' ': 1000,
    'a': 1001,
    'b': 1002
}
g = [mapping[c] for c in x]
```

Comment: Don't use `for index in range(len(...))` use `for item in ...`

Comment: No, he needs the index in the loop.

Comment: Didn't notice that. Then use `enumerate(x)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that since Python is 0-indexed, you need to adjust the end range of your loop. `len(y)` is one number, but the last index of an interable is always `len(y) - 1`. If you adjust your loop accordingly, your issue should be fixed.

However, as another user commented, if you are set on using a `while` loop, be sure to incremented it **after** the code block; otherwise you will always skip the first element.

```
while y<=len(x) - 1:
   # do code
   y += 1
```

or

```
while y < len(x):
   # do code
   y += 1
```

Even better, use a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
   # do code
```

Comment: Your `while` loop suggestion isn't quite right, because he bumps `y` as the first thing.

Comment: The first two code snippets still break since `y` gets incremented at the top of the loop

Comment: Yep, I included that at the bottom of my answer. I should probably move it up for visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with list comprehensions.

```
z = [(1000 if letter == " " else 1001 if letter == "a" else 1002 if letter == "b" else '') for letter in input("input the word: ")]
x = [y for y in z if y]
```

Comment: in stackoverflow we try to solve the problem presented first and then you can sugest another solution